# Windows 7 as VM inside VMWare Fusion - 32 or 64 bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, macbook, vmware-fusion

I have a MacBook Pro with the 2.4 Core 2 Duo and 4 GB RAM. I want to run Windows 7 for ASP.NET development within VMWare Fusion. Since I may be doing some SharePoint 2010 work I was thinking that my install of Windows 7 would need to be the 64 bit version because SharePoint 2010 requires 64 bit Windows. As I am new to Mac OS (I am running v10.6.3) I am not sure if it would support a 64 bit OS in a Virtual Machine. Thoughts?

Comment: I know you said you're planning on doing ASP.NET dev, but this sounds more like a question for SuperUser.com

Comment: It is sometimes a tough call knowing which site to post at. I felt StackOverflow.com might have more users attempting to do what I was doing and might also be more familiar with the SharePoint 2010 64 bit requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have pretty much the same setup you do. (And I plan to do SharePoint dev too)

Latest unibody MacBook with 4GB of RAM.

I am running a 64 bit Windows 7 VM with no problem at all. It run very smoothly.

Answer (score 0):

Well after some more digging I found the answer that Windows 7 x64 was in fact supported by VMWare Fusion v3. The link is below that lists it as a supported guest operating system.

http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-10958

Answer (score 0):

It works fine. I'm using VMWare Fusion to run my x64 BootCamp installation of Windows 7.